# Projecting bounded functions on a Gaussian Hilbert Space

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\{g_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be an infinite sequence of mutually independent, normally distributed random variables, all with zero expectation and unit-variance, all defined in some probability space. I believe I can prove that if $f$ is a real-valued bounded function, then
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[\mathbf{E}(fg_n)]^2\leq\frac{2}{\pi}\sup|f|^2$$
and that $\frac{2}{\pi}$ is the best possible constant, attained by certain bounded functions.

> My question is this: has anyone seen this before and can provide reference?

Comment: A naive question, does your conjectured inequality hold true when $n=1$? i.e., no infinite sequence, just consider a single $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ random variable

Comment: @Fei Cao - yes, it holds if $n=1$, because $|E(fg)|\leq\sup|f|E(|g|)$ and the expected value of the absolute value a single standard normal variable is exactly $\sqrt{2/\pi}$

Comment: can you give an example of one of the 'certain bounded functions'

Comment: What is the meaning of $E(fg_n)$ if $f$ is not random? What is then the random variable $fX_n$?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo  - $f$ is a random, bounded variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted by the OP in a comment, the inequality
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[\mathbf{E}(fg_n)]^2\leq\frac{2}{\pi}\sup|f|^2 \quad(*)$$

is true if $\{g_n\}$ is replaced by  a single standard Gaussian variable $g$, because $$[E(fg)]^2 \le (\sup |f|)^2 [E|g|]^2 =\frac{2}{\pi} (\sup |f|)^2  \,. \quad (**)$$
The inequality $(**)$ is tight because you can take $f={\rm sgn}(g)$.

The general case $(*)$ may be reduced to the special case above by considering the
projection
$$Z:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty E(fg_n)g_n$$
and its $L^2$-normalized version, $g=Z/\|Z\|_2$.

Observe that $f-Z$ is orthogonal to every $g_n$, so $E[(f-Z)g]=0$.
Then
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[\mathbf{E}(fg_n)]^2 =E(Z^2)=[E(Zg)]^2=[E(fg)]^2$$
and we are done by $(**)$.

**Edit:**  As noted in the comment by Nate Eldredge, an orthonormal basis for $L^2(\Omega,{\cal F},P)$ cannot be entirely comprised of independent centered Gaussians (together with 1), since taking $f={\rm sgn (g_1)}$ in the above inequality would contradict Parseval's identity. You can see this even more easily by noting that, given a  sequence of independent centered gaussians $\{g_n\}$, the random variable $g_1^2-1$ is orthogonal to $g_n$ for all $n \ge 1$ and to the constant functions. (The same is true for the random variable $g_1g_2$.) Taking this further leads to Hermite polynomials [1] and Hermite polynomial chaos [2].

[1]  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials
[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_chaos

Comment: I guess an interesting consequence is that an orthonormal basis for $L^2(P)$ cannot be entirely comprised of centered Gaussians (together with 1), as then this result would contradict Parseval's identity.  I never thought about that before.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge Assuming the variables are independent, you can see this even more easily by noting that, given an orthonormal sequence of centered gaussians $\{g_n\}$ (which are jointly Gaussian), the random variable $g_1 g_2$ is orthogonal to $g_n$ for all $n \ge 1$ and to the constant functions. I expanded my answer to address this.

Comment: Oh right, the Hermite polynomials.  So I suppose I did think about this before, without noticing it. :)  Thanks!